# Strange copy/paste behavior in custom itemEditor component used in a Datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4

I'm turning to you folks for answers because this really blows my mind... Let me explain:

I'm using a slightly modified spark NumericStepper as an item editor in a datagrid. I had to modify the original because for some reason it's values only went up to 10.

So i extended NumericStepper like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:NumericStepper xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                   maximum="100000000">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
</mx:NumericStepper>
```

And used it like this in my Datagrid column declaration:

```
<mx:DataGridColumn dataField="cost" itemEditor="package.to.custom.NumericStepper" editorDataField="value"/>
```

Up to here, everything normal. Valeus are perfectly updated and all.

Now when I was filling the datagrid and using **ctrl+v** to paste values in the editor, the values get doubled (pasting '123' yields '123123'). When pasting through the **right-click** menu item "**Paste**" (It's an AIR app), though, everything works perfectly (pasting '123' shows '123').

I'm puzzled by this behavior. Have I done something wrong in the declaration of the component? or in the way it is used in the datagrid? And why do both paste methods give different results?

I'd appreciate any light shed on this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is still having this problem, which exists on all mx NumericSteppers, here is what Adobe had to say:
https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-18278

Comment: Well, I guess that settles it :/